# Spring RestTemplate PATCH: the way of mapping my DTO with external one

Tags: json, rest, http, spring-mvc

I have a PATCH request endpoint for partial updating persons in my application:

```
@PatchMapping("/person/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updatePerson(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody String patchJson) {
    service.updatePerson(id, patchJson);
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```

`patchJson` will be like this:

```
{
    ...
    "someDate": "2020-09-04",
    "someType": "MANAGER",
    ...
    "fields_specific_to_my_entity": ...
}
```

But also I need to partial update an entity in an external service using some fields from `Person` entity, just partially updated in my app.

There is a method for this with using `RestTemplate` calls:

```
public void patchExternal(Long extId, ExtServiceDto extServiceDto) {
    HttpEntity<ExtServiceDto> request = new HttpEntity<>(extServiceDto);
    restTemplate.exchange(extApiUrl, HttpMethod.PATCH, request, Some.class);
}
```

JSON for calling external API should have a few fields from patchJson and some other:

```
{
    ...
    "someDate": "2020-09-04",
    "someType": "MANAGER",
    ...
    "ext_api_fields": ...
}
```

**The question is**: what is the most correct way to map patchJson to extServiceDto?

The main difficulty is to distinguish null fields, with fields which deliberately was set to null.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I've done manual mappings with something like:

```
  Optional.ofNullable(newItem.getName()).orElse(existingItem.getName()));
```

It is tedious for lots of fields, but if you have a case where you don't want to accidentally null out a field, this works.

Alternatively, https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html can be used to copy fields from your DTO, but the null filtering is harder.